# ng new not working when I tried to create a new application

Tags: angular

I tried to create a new angular app using **ng new** but after creating all the necessary files, it said **installing packages...**. 
After I waited for 10 minutes,it's still at **installing packages**. Am using node 14 and npm 6.14.x

Please what's the problem?

Comment: I've faced a similar issue when I had a poor connection. This command downloads many packages so it might be the case. Could you check your internet connection? [Netflix Fast](http://fast.com/)

Comment: My network is ok But it's not installing. I did it thrice and still the same problem. Am new to angular and this is giving me a second thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ng new ProjectName
```

creates a new project as well as downloads npm packages for a size of about 300mb required for your project. (node_modules folder)

You can skip those using :

```
ng new ProjectName --skip-install
```

and run npm install later

Comment: Ok. Let me try that. Should I run the npm install in my project root directory?

Comment: yes go to your project root directory and run npm install or npm i